# (iphone) build xcode4 project from command line

Tags: iphone, command-line, build, xcode4

I've used to build my project with
xcodebuild -proj MyProject.xcodeproj -target MyTarget - configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator4.3

this works(it builds fine) but when I hit run in xcode, it recompiles.
(with xcode3, there was no need to rebuild once I build using command line)

I suspect xcode build use workspace/scheme rather than project/target.

How do I find out the workspace name that my current xcode project is using?

Thank you

- edit

Chetan's links gave me directions what to look for.

xcode4 stores build output in ~/Library/... 
whereas xcodebuild -project .. saves build output in project's build directory.
(if you want the workspace capability, you can't use the build directory for build output)

I created a workspace containing my project and ran
xcodebuild -workspace myWorkSpace -scheme myScheme

this saves build output in ~/Library/...../**Debug-iphoneos**

whereas xcode4 run button from the same workspace and same scheme saves output in
~/Library/..../**Debug-iphonesimulator**

any guess on why xcodebuild command uses Debug-iphoneos? :(

- edit2

xcodebuild -workspace myWorkSpace -scheme myScheme -sdk iphonesimulator4.3
specifying sdk solved it

Comment: - http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/06/building-xcode-4-projects-from-the-command-line/ - http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/06/running-xcode-4-unit-tests-from-the-command-line/ - http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1124465

Answer (score 1):

I know it isn't strictly the answer to your question, but you can configure the output directory of your build using the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` environment variable.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH1-SW1